# Getting react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useId in react when creating polygon bounding annotation

Tags: reactjs, react-konva, konva

I am getting TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useId in my react app.

I am using `konva` and `react-konva`that lets a user to draw a polygon bounding annotation following this blog https://devmuscle.com/blog/react-konva-image-annotation.

Also, I currently have the v17.0.2 version of react. Is this error because of the old version because it mentions that they can't find the `useId()` and this hook came in v18. Can anyone guide me on this?

[Error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViLUJ.png)

I created a codesandbox and it works there because it has the latest of every package. For reference, please visit: https://codesandbox.io/s/polygon-c96r82?file=/src/App.js